# sinon not detecting private function called inside promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon

i am quit new to sinon and rewire. I am trying to check if private function was called with in promise. Private function stubbed is getting called, But sinon not detecting the call. below is my code snipped.

#### file.test.js

```
var fileController = rewire('./file')

var stub = sinon.stub().returns("abc")
fileController.__set__('privFunc', stub)
fileController.sampleFunc()
expect(stub).to.be.called
```

#### file.js

```
let otherFile = require('otherFile')

var privFunc = function(data) {

}

var sampleFunc = function() {
    otherFile.buildSomeThing.then(function(data) {
        privFunc(data)
    })
}

module.exports = {sampleFunc}
```

In above code snipped, privFunc is actually getting called ie. stub is getting called, But sinon not detecting call.

```
var privFunc = function(data) {

}

var sampleFunc = function() {
    privFunc(data)
}

module.exports = {sampleFunc}
```

But this above snippet works fine. ie. when private function is called directly

Comment: Unless `sampleFunc` returns the promise it's creating, you won't know *when* to check if the stub was called. `otherFile.buildSomeThing` is asynchronous.

Comment: @MarkMeyer, sorry can you  pls elaborate, buildSomeThing is function from different module and it returns promise which actually resolves successfully

Comment: `buildSomething` may return a promise, but `sampleFunc` doesn't return anything. So when you call `sampleFunc` you have no way to know when `buildSomething` has finished. You need to be able to call `sampleFunc.then(() => test_if_stubb_is_called`). To do that `sampleFunc` need to return the promise `return otherFile.buildSomeThing.then(...`

Comment: @MarkMeyer, Yes i made silly mistake of not awaiting fileController.sampleFunc(). now it works fine. Thanks, Please post you answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `otherFile.buildSomeThing` is async, you need to await it before checking if the `privFunc` stub has been called.

e.g:

**file.js**

```
let otherFile = require('otherFile')

var privFunc = function(data) {

}

var sampleFunc = function() {
    return otherFile.buildSomeThing.then(function(data) {
        privFunc(data)
    })
}

module.exports = {sampleFunc}
```

**file.test.js**

```
var fileController = rewire('./file')

var stub = sinon.stub().returns("abc")
fileController.__set__('privFunc', stub)
fileController.sampleFunc().then(() => {
  expect(stub).to.have.been.called;
});
```

If you're using mocha, you could use something like this:

```
describe('file.js test cases', () => {
  let stub, reset;
  let fileController = rewire('./file');

  beforeEach(() => {
    stub = sinon.stub().returns("abc");
    reset = fileController.__set__('privFunc', stub);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    reset();
  });

  it('sampleFunc calls privFunc', async () => {
    await fileController.sampleFunc();
    expect(stub).to.have.been.called;
  });
});
```